# Where is my "receiver app URL in Developer Console"

Tags: chromecast, drm, m3u8

I am following the directions here:

```
https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM
```

In order to understand how I can stream DRM videos with m3u8 to Google ChromeCast (from iOS).

Under 'Steps to setup'. The 3rd step says

1. Point your **receiver app URL in Developer Console to** 
   localhost/~username/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM/mpl.html

I don't know what my 'receiver app url' is. Is that referring to ?
     http://url.of.chromecast.72:9222

Is this the URL you setup when you are at https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview and you select "Add new application" of type "Custom Receiver". Then under Receiver details you are allowed to put in a 'URL'?

And for 'developer console' - I assume it's referring to?
     https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer console is where you had pointed to. The receiver URL is the one you had guessed; when you create a custom receiver, you need to specify where the receiver code is to load it from and you need to point it to wherever you are serving your receiver page at.; it has nothing to do with the chromecast ip/url.

Comment: Do you know if my 'localhost' will suffice in this circumstance?

Comment: No, localhost won't work. If your receiver is in your local network, it has to be an ip address so that chromecast can find the receiver; localhost, from chromecast point of view, points to itself which is not what you want. It shouldn't be a name either since names will be resolved using Google's DNS server which would not know about your internal network, so it should be ip address.